# Icons in Unity launcher look black

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, icons, desktop-environments

A few days ago I turn on my computer and when Linux started, the icons on the desktop look black, I tried reinstalling the desktop, the gnome-shell, updating but nothing happens. I attached a picture with the problem.

[image: Image with the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is due Compiz setting of the current user - for some reason they are mixed. We can experience similar issues when tring to tweak our desktop by using the package `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

An easy way to examine whether this is the issue is to login as another user - probably the icons will look as normal.

If you are delete all Compiz settings and logout/login, Ubuntu will create them with their default values. Another way is to copy the configuration files from another user's home directory.

You can use the following commands to find all directories related to Compiz and respectively to delete them (where `~` stands for the path to the current user's home):

```
find ~ -type d -name "*compiz*" -ls
find ~ -type d -name "*compiz*" -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the list and delete like in the first answer:

i.e.

```
find ~ -type d -name "*compiz*" -ls 
find ~ -type d -name "*compiz*"-delete
```

but it didn't work. So I remove and then install "compiz"

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove compiz
```

***WARNING DON'T SHUTDOWN BEFORE REINSTALL***

Then install

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Then install unity

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Finally reset it

```
unity --reset
```

Hope it will help.